# Installing Ubuntu error

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, wubi

I'm installing ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS using Wubi. When I restart my PC, I got a error about verifition or signature maybe. Then it's reboot back to Windows. I don't khow what going on.

Comment: Can you indicate which version of Ubuntu you are trying to install? Add the information to your question, i.e., use "edit".

Comment: Is wubi supported any more? Not in a position to check, but I thought not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be an issue with secure boot. Try disabling it in the UEFI-BIOS. If you don't find the option, try searching for "<mainboard/laptop> disable secure boot". If it doesn't work, enable it afterwards.